# Powershell: how to check if string contains any significant characters?

Tags: regex, string, powershell

I need to check a string to see if it conatins anything other than spaces, returns, etc.

In perl, I used:

```
if($val =~/^\s*$/) {...}
```

How do I do that in PowerShell?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the `-match` operator:

```
if ($test -match 'regex_here') { 'It matched' }
```

Also check the online docs for comparison operators: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx

Comment: I found http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-regex.html to be helpful. It looks like what I want is, $string -match "\s+"

Comment: Jeff, another trick is `$val.Trim().length`. That will delete all leading/trailing whitespace characters. `length` will be 0 if all that's all there was.

Answer (score 0):

if("~/^\s*$/".ToCharArray() -Contains $val){"…"}